# Custom router in module "Sample New Page" wont work

Tags: magento2, module

I am a beginner in Magento Magento 2. I'm trying to learn how to develop module for mage but I have problem with custom routing in module.

**Here's what I've done:**

1. I cloned from their repo and installed by the composer.
2. I downloaded the 'sample-module-newpage' from the repo https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples
3. I placed sample-module-newpage in the *app/code/Magento/sample-module-newpage*.
4. Then I enable the module with command: `enable Magento_SampleNewPage`
5. Then I was executed command `magento setup:update`

**Now couple things:**

- In Magento backoffice *stores -> configuration -> advanced -> advanced* in section *Disable Modules Output* I can see that **Magento_SampleNewPage** is enabled
- I disabled Magento cache
- I'm not sure if it should look like this but to the admin panel 
  I get through exaple.com/**index.php**/admin
- After installation Magento wasn't able to load css and js depedencies because of wrong file path. To fix this I was run two commands `magento setup:static-content:deploy` and `magento indexer:reindex`

**My problem**

I'm not able to access example page which is created by my module. Readme says that *page can be accessed at /newpage* but I'm getting apache 404. I've tried also at  */index.php/newpage* but I'm getting magento error that page doesn't exists.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to clean up var/ folder ?

Comment: If u mean deleting everyting from var/cache then yes. And still the same.

Comment: You can feel free to delete all files inside var folder. Just keep .htacess as is.

Comment: Your Admin URL should not include `index.php`. Did you enable [Apache rewrites](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite)?

Comment: Ok, everything work's fine now. I moved from Nginx to Apache with mod-rewrite. Clearing `var` folder after adding module to magento is not enough. After adding new module to magento 2, I am executing folowing commands `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` then I am clearing `var` folder and at the end I'm setting chmods agin with following commands `sudo chmod -R 777 var` `sudo chmod -R 777 app/etc` `sudo chmod -R 777 pub`. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/index.php/newpage/index/index/
```

or

```
/newpage/index/index/
```

The module frontname is `newpage` definded in `/etc/frontend/routes.xml` line 10.

The controller lives in the `index` folder with the name `index` so you should add `index/index` to the url.

URL Syntax

```
{magento-base-url}/index.php/{route frontName}/{controller folder}/{controller class}/
```

More info: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-controllers/

Answer (score -1):

Try to push module code to 
`app/code/Magento/SampleNewPage` folder